# 3.9.5 patch download for Mule Runtime

Tags: mule, mulesoft

ee-patch-3.9.5-20211223-DECEMBER-2021.zip on their forums but link says invalid, can someone help me to get that patch to my mule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only MuleSoft customers that paid for the enterprise edition have access to patches. If you are a customer you can to login to https://help.mulesoft.com and download available files from there.

Comment: Thanks @aled, is not 3.9.5 CE ? cause my script got works after i upgrade to 3.9.5 from 3.9.0 but i want to update all files on my mule runtime about log4j and log4j2

Comment: Usually CE (Community Edition) releases end in .0 because they get no patches/fixes. Maybe you downloaded a trial EE (Enterprise Edition) release?

Comment: I found 3.9.5.zip available at their repo url so i download it..and it works... https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/service/local/repositories/releases/content/org/mule/distributions/mule-standalone/3.9.5/

Comment: That appears to be a community release of Mule 3.9.5. The patch you mentioned is for the EE release (ee-patch...).

Comment: So no patch are required for 3.9.5 versions?

https://i.imgur.com/ysMWozk.png 

According per this screenshot i think i still need to update my CE version

Comment: I didn't say that no patches are required. What I said is that MuleSoft doesn't provide patches for CE. You question was about access to a patch, that is what I was trying to answer. If you want to ask another question about the log4j vulnerability please do it in by posting a new question. You can see that the CE release downloaded uses an older log4j2 library.

Comment: Thanks @aled, helpful as always! :)